# dplyr summarize multiple column

Tags: r, plyr

I have a simple `dataframe` with the following column name

```
Subject # Type #  Value0 # value1# value2# ....value100
```

I want to use the `dplyr` summarize operation in order to get the mean of each value columns. 
I think there is a useful alternative to

```
ddply(dataframe, c("Subject,Type"), summarize, m1= mean(value1), m2=mean(value2)....)
```

If I gather all Value column name in a list

```
names =c("Value0,Value1,....Value100)
```

How can I use this list in `ddply`?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `summarise_each`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(Subject, Type) %>%
     summarise_each(funs(mean= mean(., na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Comment: Thank. But If i want the mean for each column from Value0 to Value5 ?

Comment: @user2226667  Have you tried the code?  It is giving the mean for each column.

Comment: @user2226667 `summarise_each(funs(mean), Value0:Value5)` is the way you should be able to do that.